# Django Template Tag - Display only one value in nested for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working on a Django web app and have the following query:

I have a model called 'AppQoSList' which lists the applications available to all users.

I have then another model called 'BasicAppSDWANProfiles' which has a ManyToMany relationship with 'AppQoSList' .

In short, it means a user can have multiple 'BasicAppSDWANProfiles' associated to his account and multiple AppQoS can be within a particular BasicAppSDWANProfiles:

```
class AppQoSList(models.Model):

    app_qos_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=None, null=True)
    app_qos_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.app_qos_name


class BasicAppSDWANProfiles(models.Model):
    profile_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    profile_basic_app_qos = models.ManyToManyField(AppQoSList)
    tenant_id = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, default=3)
```

I'm facing issue in my template when I try to display the list of apps available and the associated BasicAppSDWANProfile:

```
{%  for app in apps %}
     {% for profile_app in sdwan_prof %}
        {% for specific_app in profile_app.profile_basic_app_qos.all %}
                {% ifchanged specific_app.pk %}
                    {% if app.pk == specific_app.pk %}
          <td><h4><span class="label label-primary">{{ profile_app.profile_name }}</span></h4></td>
                    {% else %}
         <td><h4><span class="label label-warning">Not Assigned</span></h4></td>
                    {% endif %}
                 {% endifchanged %}
         {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
```

Issue with this code is that 'Not Assigned' is displayed 6 times on each row (which corresponds to the number of Apps found in BasicAppSDWANProfiles associated with this user) whereas I would like to display it only once:

[image: Table Visual]

Would you have any solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you really want to show then ?

Comment: I find it hard understanding what you want to display. do you want to show the profile on just one column?

Comment: I would like to display the Profile Name value if it has an app associated. If not, I would like to display 'Not Assigned' but only once. Hope that clarifies

Answer (score 1):

I was able to address this issue.

First I did clean up my view code to remove duplicate 'Not Assigned' values.

I pass to my template context a dictionary with only apps that have a profile assigned such as below:

```
{'citrix-static': 'DPS-BLACKLIST',
 'exchange': 'DPS-BLACKLIST',
 'ms-lync-audio': 'DPS-WHITELIST',
 'ms-update': 'DPS-GREYLIST',
 'rtp': 'DPS-WHITELIST',
 'share-point': 'DPS-WHITELIST'}
```

In my template, I only loop through this dictionary:

```
               {% for k,v in app_prof_assign.items %}

                      {% if app.app_qos_name == k %}

                <td><h4><span class="label label-primary">{{ v }}</span></h4></td>

                    {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}
```

I then simply check if the app is not in the profile dictionary, **outside** the loop:

```
    {%  if app.app_qos_name not in app_prof_assign %}
  <td><h4><span class="label label-warning">Not Assigned</span></h4></td>
    {% endif %}
```

Finally, I can get the table populated as expected:

[image]